# ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for CompaniesController):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I running a webrick, and shell show me this error

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for CompaniesController):
```

there is my routes.rb

```
  resources :companies do
    member do
      put :click_on
    end
    get :generator, on: :collection
  end
  root 'welcome#welcome_page'
```

the controller no `index` action

how fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `index` action (which is just a method) to your controller like the error message suggests:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Then add views to render:

```
<%# app/views/companies/index.html.erb %>
<h1>Companies Index</h1>
```

Read the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for more information on how controller basics work.

Comment: No, is not the problem case.It worked before without `index` action

Comment: The error message is a bit vague here I think. The action method is indeed not required, but you will get this error if the action method is missing in combination with missing views. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, man.But it is not solution.I think a problem in the other place

Comment: Are you still getting that very same error after you've tried this solution? If so, can you post more code so the issue can hopefully be identified?

Comment: I was solved this problem.I stupid :) I was put jquery script in to assets.And this script was call `index` action

Comment: Ah, so the `index` action wasn't supposed to exist at all? I didn't understand that from the question though. Glad to hear you've found the problem!

Comment: yes, `index` action wasn't supposed to exist at all.Thanks again, sorry for my bad English.Good luck!